# difference between Recycler view and card view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I know card view is used when working with recycler view, but I was watching some tutorials and found out that card views can be used individually without the recycler view. So which way is the correct and better way?

Comment: they don't do the same thing https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview.
a recycler view can make use of several card views OR ANY VIEWS

Comment: from the links i sent you, it says that a recycler is used: `If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements`. a recycler is simply a scrolling list of views, in this case it contains card views

Comment: oh, I understand now. Thanks for helping. @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically there is no relation between them, each component designed for a goal.
You can use the RecyclerView to display a list of items or objects, and the CardView to display some data of that object.

Comment: That is what i'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By using CardView you can represent the information in a card manner with a drop shadow (elevation) and corner radius which looks consistent across the platform.

You can achieve good looking UI when CardView is combined with RecyclerView.
The RecyclerView is a more advanced and more flexible version of the ListView.